# Set of Class Objects

Tags: c++, class, constructor, set, initializer-list

I have defined a set of class objects, the class being Person. The following is the code -

```
#include<iostream>
#include<set>
#include<functional>
using namespace std;

class Person {
    public:
        int age;
        string name;
    bool operator < (const Person& rhs) const { return age < rhs.age; }
};
int main()
{
    set<Person> Set = { (18,"John"),(16,"Sean") };
    for (const auto& e: Set)
    {
        cout << e.age << " " << e.name;;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting the following error when I build the code -

```
Error   C2664   'Person::Person(Person &&)': cannot convert argument 1 from '_Ty' to 'const Person &'
```

I am just trying to iterate over all the elements(class objects) of the set and print their values, but I have no idea why this error shows up. I have searched for it online and got nothing. I think that the error may be in the compare function that I am writing, but I just learned all this today and now I'm stuck. Can someone please guide me through?

Comment: Fyi, you're missing `<string>` in your include list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write

```
set<Person> Set = { {18,"John"},{16,"Sean"} };
```

That is you need to use braces instead of parentheses.

When there are parentheses instead of braces then for example this expression

```
( 18,"John" )
```

is an expression with the comma operator. Its value is the value of the second operand that is `"John"`. So the compiler is considering the declaration like

```
set<Person> Set = { "John", "Sean" };
```

And you need to include the header `<string>`.